# saving the file path for multiple image upload in sql

Tags: php, sql, database, image, forms

i used the following code to upload multiple image upload to a folder located in server each file will be renamed random method now what i need is i just want to store the image file path SQL database here is my code

```
<?php
class Upload_Rename{
const ALLOWED_TYPES = "jpg,gif,png";
public static function   generate_new_name($extension,$uppercase=true,$prefix='',$sufix=''){
    $new_name = $prefix.uniqid().'_'.time().$sufix;
    return ($uppercase ? strtoupper($new_name) : $new_name).'.'.$extension;
}
public static function check_and_get_extension($file){
    $file_part      = pathinfo($file);
    $allowed_types  = explode(",",Upload_Rename::ALLOWED_TYPES);
    if(!in_array($file_part['extension'], $allowed_types)){
        throw new Exception('Not ok.. bad bad file type.');
    }
    return $file_part['extension'];
}
public function upload($file,$target_destination){
    if(!isset($file['tmp_name'])){
        throw new Exception('Whaaaat?');
    }
    $_name   = $file['name'];
    $_tmp    = $file['tmp_name'];
    $_type   = $file['type'];
    $_size   = $file['size'];
    $file_extension = '';
    try{
        $file_extension = Upload_Rename::check_and_get_extension($_name);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        throw new Exception('Ops.. file extension? what? '.$e->getMessage());
    }
    $new_name    =   Upload_Rename::generate_new_name($file_extension,true,'whaat_','_okey');
    $destination = $target_destination . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $new_name;
    return move_uploaded_file($_tmp, $destination);
}
public function multiple_files($files,$destination){
    $number_of_files = isset($files['tmp_name']) ? sizeof($files['tmp_name']) : 0;
    $errors = array();
    for($i=0;$i<$number_of_files;$i++){
        if(isset($files['tmp_name'][$i]) && !empty($files['tmp_name'][$i])){
            try{
                $this->upload(array(
                    'name'=>$files['name'][$i],
                    'tmp_name'=>$files['tmp_name'][$i],
                    'size'=>$files['size'][$i],
                    'type'=>$files['type'][$i]
                ),$destination);
            }catch(Exception $e){
                array_push($errors,array('file'=>$files['name'][$i],'error'=>$e->getMessage()));
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($errors);
}
}
if($_FILES){
$upload = new Upload_Rename();
$destination ='upload/';
$upload->multiple_files($_FILES['myfile'],$destination);
}
?>

<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php for($i=0;$i<10;$i++): ?>
file: <input type="file" name="myfile[]"><br>
<?php endfor; ?>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

i need to store image path in SQL to retrieve it in another PHP page

Answer (score 0):

You should create a column in your mysql table. 
Lets say you are name it image_path.
What i will show you here is a pseudo code, so you will have to adjust it for your needs.
As i can see you have the method

```
public function multiple_files($files,$destination)
```

whit sill i suppose return true if success otherwise will thrown an exception.
What you should do is to create a method to save your path in DB, in field image_path.

So, after this part here:

```
$destination ='upload/';
$upload->multiple_files($_FILES['myfile'],$destination);
```

add newly created method, eg. savePath($path)

```
$path = $destination . '/' . $file_name;
$this->savePath($path)
```

and you should be good to go.
Since i dont know how you are handling your database connection and recording that part should be on you.

Best regards
Vladimir

Comment: how do i save file path to sql database

Comment: You are saving it as any other record.
so, create a separated method, which will be recording data. 
if you dont know how to connect to db and insert record, do a little bit googling by 'how to insert record in sql using php' and that should help you.